# mysql UNIX_TIMESTAMP returns incorrect value

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following date in mysql stored in DATETIME field:

```
2012-04-16 16:21:54
```

Than I select it like this:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) ....
```

but if I print the hour using php date function I get one hour difference:

```
echo date("H:i:s", $row->date)
```

would print:

```
17:21:54
```

Without the second parameter, the date function returns correct value. Any ideas?

Comment: `date()` function will convert the date to the server time before displaying it. The one hour difference could be the expected result.

Comment: are the database and web server same? If they are different, do they have same timezones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to mysql manual -

`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`, `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date)`

If called with no argument, returns a Unix timestamp (seconds since '1970-01-01 00:00:00' UTC) as an unsigned integer. If `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` is called with a date argument, it returns the value of the argument as seconds since '1970-01-01 00:00:00' UTC. date may be a DATE string, a DATETIME string, a TIMESTAMP, or a number in the format YYMMDD or YYYYMMDD. The server ***interprets date as a value in the current time zone and converts it to an internal value in UTC***. Clients can set their time zone as described in Section 10.6, “MySQL Server Time Zone Support”.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: i made the line in bold. that explains the reason.

Comment: Thanks, that's the correct answer. Running SET @@global.time_zone = 'America/New_York'; query solve the problem!

Answer (score 0):

with adding 'e' you can get the timezone for that timestamp.

It has probably something to do with different timezones. Try using http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-timezone-set.php.

If that won't work, explore the rest of the date function:
http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php